# How do I start a separate bash script within a bash script?

Tags: bash, dialog

This really is terrible. I've tried so many (if not all) of the various ways to start a separate bash script from within a bash script.

This actually is how I simplified the troubleshooting:

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE="Simple Script Function"

#This actually is the path to the script I want to start.
ROBUST="/GrEase (for Diasteirasein)"


function start_separate_script() {
source "$ROBUST" 
}

dialog --title "$TITLE" --clear \
   --yesno "You're about to start a script. \n\n          Are you ready?"      11 41

return_value=$?
if [ "$return_value" = "1" ]
then
dialog --title "$TITLE" --clear \
     --msgbox "You seem unsure of yourself." 11 41
exit
else
dialog --title "$TITLE" --clear \
     --msgbox "If you programmed your function correctly & you can incite a separate script out of this script, then your script should now start." 11 41
start_separate_script;
#Simply does not work.
# :(
exit
fi
```

I would greatly appreciate the help.
Thanks.
:)

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What does it do?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a two-liner to reproduce your problem? `ROBUST="/GrEase (for Diasteirasein)"; source "$ROBUST"` - does this have your problem?

Comment: With a little help of somebody within the #bash IRC channel I was able to figure it out intuitively. I did a cat 'GrEase (for Diasteirasein)' & I figured out that I was identifying the path to the script inappropriately. I should use single quotes & exclude "/" when identifying a path within the same file folder.

Comment: @JasonClandestino "Within the same file folder" is more complicated than that -- by default, you'll be looking for files in the folder the user was in when they ran the script, which might be somewhere completely else. See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) for some options (it's about looking for config files, but exactly the same considerations apply to helper scripts).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, that's precisely the problem that I am coping with now. First I'll start with a brief usage outline: I'm making a simple text based user interface for a server software. I have a series of bash scripts that are intended to start & stop servers. The scripts are simplified with a package directory that has the primary script & then needs to navigate to a subfolder with the other package scripts. I am having difficulty getting to the subfolder to run those other scripts, which is primarily where this problem started. Thanks for referencing the link.

Comment: Why are you sourcing it (source means that you are including a code into your script) and not executing it, instead of `start_separate_script` you could just insert directly `/GrEase (for Diasteirasein)` as your are actually in an if statement and if you want it background do `/GrEase (for Diasteirasein) &`

Answer (score 0):

**Second script** (~/bin/y.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Second script"
```

**Primary script** (~/bin/x.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE="Simple Script Function"
#This actually is the path to the script I want to start.
ROBUST=~/bin/y.sh

function start_separate_script() {
    source "$ROBUST" 
}

zenity --question \
       --title "$TITLE" \
       --text "You're about to start a script. \n\n          Are you ready?"
return_value=$?

if [ "$return_value" = "1" ]; then
    zenity --question \
           --title "$TITLE" \
           --text "You seem unsure of yourself."
    exit
else
    read -r -d '' MSG <<HERE
If you programmed your function correctly &amp;
you can incite a separate script out of this script,
then your script should now start.
HERE

    zenity --question \
           --title "$TITLE" \
           --text "${MSG}"
    start_separate_script;
    exit
fi
```

**Permissions**

```
chmod +x ~/bin/x.sh ~/bin/y.sh
```

**Dependencies**

```
sudo apt install zenity
```

**Result**

```
$ ~/bin/x.sh
Second script!
```